# Getting PowerShell to post all information to out file

Tags: powershell

PowerShell is writing information to file when I delete a registry entry successfully however I also need it to post errors to the file instead of the PS session.

```
Remove-Item -Path $path -Force -Verbose 4>&1 | Out-File "c:\registryresults.txt"
```

How would I be best able to achieve this?

Comment: Add `2>&1` or change `4>&1` to `*>&1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`4>&1` is the 'Verbose' stream being redirected to the 'output' stream.

you probably want to use `*>&1` or just `*> "c:\registryresults.txt"` on its own without the `Out-File`